# Copy files from one directory to another without replacement

Tags: java, file, path, copy, nio

So I cannot seem to find a suitable way to copy files from one directory to another without overwriting a file with the same name. All existing java methods I have seen overwrite existing files(FileUtils) or throw an exception(Files nio)

For example if I have a file struct like:

```
├───srcDir
│   ├───this.txt
│   ├───hello.txt
│   ├───main.java

├───destDir
│   ├───this.txt
```

I want to copy over `hello.txt` and `main.java` however I do not want to copy/update/replace `this.txt`

I am trying this approach:

```
try{
    DirectoryStream<path> files = Files.newDirecotryStream(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(srcDir);
    for(Path f : files)
        if(Files.notExists(f))
            Files.copy(f, Paths.get(targetDir).resolve(f.getFileName()));

}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which doesn't work obviously because I'm just checking if `f` does not exist in in the src directory which of course it exists because that's where I'm pulling from.

I really want to say something like `if(Files.notExists(f) in target directory)`
but I'm not sure if that's possible.

So is this the an appropriate approach? Is there a better way? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simple java.io.* classes?

Comment: @zerocool yeah my initial attempt was to use File but was immediately told to use the more updated nio which has been a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to create a File object for target file, and then check if it exists, something like:

```
for(Path f : files) {
    String targetPath = targetDir + System.getProperty("file.separator") + f.getFileName;
    File target = new File(targetPath);
    if(!target.exists())
        Files.copy(f, Paths.get(targetDir).resolve(f.getFileName()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! would you know how this would differ if targetDir contained sub-directories?

Comment: I'm assuming that targetDir is the path of where you want to put the file, either a full path from root dir, or a relative path from current directory.  Should not matter whether targetDir has sub directories, unless you also want to check those to see if it has a file with this name.  `target.exists()` will return true if there is either a file or directory with that name.